# Force SSL redirect via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

In APACHE is there any simple way (just by modifying my .htaccess) to force users who just go to mysite.com to be redirected to https://mysite.com

for security reasons I need users to always be on the "https" version of my site and not on the "http" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For https redirection of only `http://domain.com/`:**

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]
```

**For https redirection of everything under `http://domain.com/`:**

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I do have a question! If I am already using RewrtieEngine for somethign else... is the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` going to mess with that?

Comment: No it should not. In case you have any problem just post your other rule in your question and I will debug.

Comment: Ah! Well I did have a problem, but I just stuck your rule above mine and it all started working! Https rule before the rest of the URL rules was good for me! Thankyou so much for offering so much help! God bless!